# search documents in liferay

Tags: search, indexing, liferay, documents

I am a beginner with life-ray and I am facing a simple task,which I don't have the slightest idea of how to deal with:

**I want to build a portlet which uses the API to add files to liferay. These files should appear in the global search portlet.**

Please, tell me where to start I've read several tutorials like http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Adding+search+capabilities+to+a+portlet and http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/-asset-framewo-4
,but I feel that these tutorials skip some important steps.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to build the custom portlet for adding files in liferay. They have provide in build portlet for it. you can just add Document and Media Portlet.

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Document+Library+Portlet

Comment: The point is that I want this to happen automatically, for example there is a folder somewhere and once I have added a file inside the folder, liferay should index it and then somehow display it in the search - not exactly as Documents' portlet, is it?